# Python requests makes a lot of post requests, what should I do?

Tags: python, django

The project is written in Django.

There is a function in views.py that should make a POST request to the API of one site. But for some reason the script does not work correctly, the update is very slow, and a ConnectionError is thrown. But the POST request is sent several times, and eventually creates several records in the database on the site. There don't seem to be any cycles. What's wrong?

views.py:

```
@login_required(login_url='login-main')
def send_program_to_orchard(request, orchard_pk, pk, user_pk):
    services.send_program_to_orchard(orchard_pk, pk)
    return redirect(request.path)
```

services.py:

```
def make_json(program_id):
    program = Program.objects.get(id=program_id)
    program_substances = ProgramSubstance.objects.filter(program=program)
    response = {
        'program_number': program.number,
        'program_substances': []
    }
    for each in program_substances:
        response['program_substances'].append({'date': each.date.isoformat(), 'substance': each.substance, 'dose': float(each.dose),
                                               'measurement': each.measurement, 'comment': each.comment})
    return json.dumps(response)


def send_program_to_orchard(orchard_pk, program_pk):
    orchard = Orchard.objects.get(id=orchard_pk)
    headers = {'Authorization': f'Token {orchard.API_token}'}
    data = {'data': make_json(program_pk)}
    requests.post(orchard.program_API, headers=headers, data=data)
```

Comment: Unfortunately without more details it's impossible to say.  Maybe you could put a `breakpoint()` in `send_program_to_orchard` to see why it's being called in ways you didn't expect.  Otherwise from what we have there's nothing to suggest an obvious problem.

Comment: Could it be that the `redirect(request.path)` you return forces the client into a loop?